# how to map root to a resource in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a resource called posts, now i want to map root to posts as a resource.
so as the result:

'/posts' => nothing

'/posts/1' => nothing

but

'/' => posts#index

'/1' => posts#show

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In `config/routes.rb` change

```
resources :posts
```

to:

```
resources :posts, :path => '/'
```